# Can we hyper start muscles

Tags: technological-development

Is there a way we could hyper start muscles so they can move the speed of sound individually. And make it temporary. And a suit that can survive at that speed and a sonic boom.

Comment: No, sorry it is impossible. We can increase muscle strength and speed but not that much.

Comment: Have you considered powered exoskeletons? They might be able to move at the speed of sound.

Comment: You like to have Flash but for real?) Iron man is more real. Flash is cute.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to have a real life Flash.  Unfortunately, if I take the time to sum up all of the physically plausible parts of the flash, the list is:

- He's human.  We know humans exist

That's about it.

I usually prefer to sell a story of things being plausible, because I'd rather people reach for the stars.  However, The Flash just isn't plausible.  Sorry.  The number of problems with a Flash-like metahuman are... well... immense.

Let's start with basic physics, and then work our way up.  It is not possible to accelerate up to the speed of sound by running, much less maintain that speed.  At the speed of sound, the drag forces are immense.  As it turns out, it doesn't matter how strong you are, you are limited by how much force you can apply against the ground.  That is limited by friction.  Unless your metahuman weighs 50,000 pounds, they're not going to be able to generate enough ground friction to offset the air friction.

We've gotten land vehicles up to the sound barrier.  They look like this:
[image: Thrust SSC]

That baby is ThrustSSC, the first car to officially break the sound barrier.  That took them all the way till 1997 to accomplish.  Note it doesn't use ground friction to apply its forward force.  Those are two Rolls-Royce Spey 205 turbofans, pumping out a combined 50,000 pounds of thrust, sipping down 18 liters of gas every second.

Energy density becomes a problem.  The Flash got the munchies when he moved too fast too long, but it's nothing remotely like the real thing.  ThrustSSC consumes roughly 250MJ/s.  A BigMac, at a massive 540 Calories still only comes in at 2.2MJ.  That means a real life flash would have to eat 100 Big Macs for every second of sustained supersonic time to keep up with the ThrustSSC. (Sure, the ThrustSSC is a lot larger, but it's also far more aerodynamic than a hairless ape.  He might not have to actually eat 100 Big Macs, but it'd be a lot).

He also has to store that energy.  That's tricky.  100 Big Macs would be tough to carry.  If he could consume gasoline or diesel fuel, that'd decrease the cost, but fundamentally you're still talking about having to hold onto the equivalent of 18L of gasoline for every second of superspeed.  The only solution I can think of to this is to get bitten by a radioactive spider.  And by that, what I really mean is develop the ability to contain a nuclear reactor within your own body, so that you can take advantage of the awesome energy density of Uranium in a nuclear reactor.  No, you don't get to experiment on my body.  Make your own nuclear reactor fist, then we'll talk.

Finally, you get to the muscles.  Frankly, I love the beautiful structures we've been given that permit us to contract and relax and shape our world, but they're not up for the task.  You'll quickly run into tensile strength issues with the raw materials.  You'd also have to completely change the nervous system, as you would have to have the ability to contract and release these muscles hundreds of times faster than any muscle in the animal kingdom.

In all, if you want to move at the speed of sound, the best way to do it is to grab a few hundred gallons of jet fuel and do it the old fashioned way.

[image: F/A-18]

Comment: And you forgot aerodynamics. As the Flash leans forward for better traction, his body will create lift, and at less than 200 miles per hour will lift completely off the ground, which will obviously limit his traction.